# add comment into mysql using ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

[image]

As shown from the diagram, I have two tables in my mysql and I would like the system to add and retrieve comment without refreshing the page.

I have three php pages involved in this function and they are 'DB.php', 'comment.php' and 'action.php' The codes are as shown:

**DB.php**

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','Practical4','1234') or die (mysql_error);
    $db=mysql_select_db('Practical4', $conn) or die (mysql_error);
?>
```

**comment.php**

```
<!-- ajax script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".submit_button").click(function() {
            var textcontent = $("#content").val();
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var dataString = 'content=' + textcontent + '&name=' + name;
            if (textcontent == '') {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("#content").focus();
        }
        else {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#show").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $("#content").focus();
                }  
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div>

         <!-- retrieve hotel id from hotel table -->
<?php
include('DB.php');

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = mysql_query("select * from hotel where name='$id'");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $name=$rows['name'];
    $price=$rows['price'];
    $duetime=$rows['dueTime'];
    $address=$rows['location'];
}
?>

  <!-- post form -->
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<h3>Add Comment for <?php echo $name;?><h3>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" hidden > <br>
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="content" id="content" maxlength="145" >
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>

</form>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
include('DB.php');
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment order by commentID desc");
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
$content=$_POST['content'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

mysql_query("insert into comment (content,name) values ('$content','$name')");
echo '<div class="showbox">'.$content.'</div>';
}
?>
```

So far the code is working well, but I'd like to use JSON instead of using datastring in my ajax script, Any idea on how to change this?

Changed action.php using mysqli:

```
<?php

$DBServer = 'localhost'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'Practical4';
$DBPass   = '1234';
$DBName   = 'Practical4';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$v1="'" . $conn->real_escape_string('content') . "'";
$v2="'" . $conn->real_escape_string('name') . "'";

$sql="INSERT INTO comment (content,name) VALUES ($v1,$v2)";

if($conn->query($sql) === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $last_inserted_id = $conn->insert_id;
  $affected_rows = $conn->affected_rows;
  echo '<div class="showbox">'.$v1.'</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: very simple - convert your `dataString` to json like so (`var dataString = {'content': textcontent, 'name': name};`), then add `dataType: 'json'` to your list of ajax parameters. Congratulations, it's now using json.

Comment: Sry, sir~do u mind to show me a full picture? I am not familiar with json, indeed still new to it. @Novocaine88

Comment: I have changed my code like this, but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say your code works as is, but you just want to use `JSON` to send the data, all you need to change is the following in **comment.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".submit_button").click(function() {
            var textcontent = $("#content").val();
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var dataString = {'content': textcontent, 'name': name}; \\ HERE
            if (textcontent == '') {
                alert("Enter some text..");
                $("#content").focus();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#flash").show();
                $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "action.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: 'json', \\ AND HERE
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#show").after(html);
                        document.getElementById('content').value='';
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        $("#content").focus();
                    }  
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

`dataString` has been converted to json, and the `dataType` has been added to your ajax request.

On a side note, if you're going to use `mysql_*` functions you really need to sanitize the variables you're passing into the database. Ideally you should make use of prepared statements provided by PDO or mysqli.

**EDIT:**

Modify your `success` call to this;

```
success: function(html) {

    console.log(textcontent + ' : ' + name + ' : ' + html);

    $("#show").after(html);
    document.getElementById('content').value='';
    $("#flash").hide();
    $("#content").focus();
}
```

Then as a test comment out all of your action.php
and simply add this;

`var_dump($_POST);`

Check the console...do you get what you expect? You should see the variables as in the form.

Comment: Thanks, I have made these changes but somehow I am unable to insert new data into mysql database. Do I need to change anything in action.php?

Comment: So rather than using mysql_* in action.php, I have to use mysqli to store the data? could you please show me an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try printing out the `$_POST` variables in action.php and do a `console.log(html)` in your `success: ` function to see if the variables come through in the console. See [here](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) for an example on how to use `msqli`

Comment: Thanks! I have rewrited my action.php, which as shown above, but it still not works..Any idea why?

Comment: did you try printing out the `$_POST` variables then logging them in the console to see if they are being passed through correctly? Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: also the line `$conn->real_escape_string('content')` would need to be `$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['content'])` - otherwise you would not be using the variables you're passing in.

Comment: Hmm, Sorry~I have no idea how to debug in javascript. I putted console.log(html) in the success function and nothing showed up, is it because nothing is passed into dataString?

Comment: Yeah, I have changed to $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['content']), unfortunately it is not being inserted. Sorry to trouble you so much but I am really keen to achieve this..

Comment: by following your instruction, I encountered Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on line 11 which is this line:   var dataString = {'content': textcontent, 'name': name}; \\ HERE

Comment: Sorry, get rid of the \\ HERE comments I added in the two areas. I didn't think they would cause a problem, but apparently they do.

Comment: Cool~The record now is being added! but it is weird because what I expect is to dynamically auto-display the new record after it is added. But the system stun at 'loading' status and only display new record when I refresh page. the console says there is an error called event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. on this line  $.ajax({

Comment: try changing `$("#show").after(html);` to `$("#show").html(html);` This will replace the content within the `#show` div. Also I don't see why you have the line `document.getElementById('content').value='';` ?

Comment: Hmm, I think the error is from jquery.min.js, sorry for confusing you~

Comment: Now the situation is after I click submit, the system will just display loading.. and the new record displays only after manually refreshing the page..How can I make it auto-display the new record without refreshing page?

Comment: did you try my earlier suggestion of adding `console.log(textcontent + ' : ' + name + ' : ' + html);`? This should show you whether you're getting the correct response from the ajax call based on the third variable.

Comment: I think is the line echo '<div class="showbox">'.$v1.'</div>'; in action.php doesn't work, do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Yes, I did~ but there is nothing display in console, I will try it again.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it goes to success function. I added the line console.log(textcontent + ' : ' + name + ' : ' + html); in success function and commented out everything but var_dump($_POST);
when I submit it, nothing is displayed

Comment: It would be better to create a new question with this problem. Your original question of submitting the data via `JSON` is now answered. As the database insert code is working, the rest of your issues are to do with something else, and would likely be better answered on a new question.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have alr figured it out~Thanks a lot!